# Return a constant reference to a member variable in Ada

Tags: pointers, ada

I have a class in Ada that contains a matrix. I want to implement a function that returns it as a `constant access` type, just to be able to get it as a read only value but avoiding the unnecessary copy.

I have tried it by returning a reference to an Integer just for testing purposes:

```
package Tests_Package is
    type B is private;

    function Test(Self : in B) return access constant Integer;

    private
        type B is tagged
        record
            I : aliased Integer;
        end record;
end Tests_Package;

-------------------------------------------

package body Tests_Package is

    function Test(Self : in B) return access constant Integer is
    begin
        return Self.I'access;
    end Test;

end Tests_Package;
```

The above won't compile, the error is:  `non-local pointer cannot point to local object.`

**My questions are:**

Why exactly I get that error?

Is there any way to achieve what I want, without using `Unchecked_Access`?

Do I actually need to return the variable's reference, or the copy can be optimized out by the Ada compiler?

Comment: The copy can be optimized away. You shouldn't be worrying about it unless you have a measured failure to meet a pre-specified, quantitative timing requirement.

Comment: In this particular case, the `Self` argument of the function is passed by value. This means that the compiler `creates` a local copy of the passed value. When the function returns, this local copy does not exist anymore; thus, the returned address is invalid. To make it work, you can pass this value as `access` (aka pointer in C/C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe references were introduced in Ada 2012 by combining "anonymous access types introduced in Ada 2005" and the "Implicit_Dereference aspect introduced in Ada 2012" and described shortly here:

https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-123-implicit-dereferencing-in-ada-2012

Dan, in your specific case

```
package Tests_Package is

   type Integer_Ref
     (Element : not null access constant Integer) is limited null record with
     Implicit_Dereference => Element;

   type B is tagged private;

   function Test (Self : aliased B) return Integer_Ref;

private

   type B is tagged
      record
         I : aliased Integer := 5;
      end record;

   function Test (Self : aliased B) return Integer_Ref is
      ((Element => Self.I'Access));

end Tests_Package;
```

And is used like this:

```
with Tests_Package;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Variable : Tests_Package.B;

   Result   : Integer := 3 + Variable.Test;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Result'Img);
end Main;
```

If you try setting the private variable by "Variable.Test := 1;" you will get compile time error since you only have a read only view of the Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Make the parameter `aliased`:

```
function Test(Self : aliased in B) return access constant Integer;
```

(which forces the parameter to be passed by reference, [ARM 6.2(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-2.html#p3)

Comment: Your code + my modification compiles with GCC 6, 7, 8 and GNAT CE 2016, 2017, 2018. No idea what the difference is (of course, your type B is tagged, so it’s by-reference anyway. Huh.)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error message because the compiler can't guarantee that you can't retain the reference to the entity after it goes out of scope/disappears.

There are some tricks with the aspect `Implicit_Dereference`, which should solve your problem.